# explain how sort used for reversing an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, reverse

Can anyone explain how this work, how sort reverses the array in `a.sort(b=>1)`?

example:

```
var a = [1,2,[],'b',5]
a.sort(b=>1)
```

gives this:

```
a=[5,'b',[],2,1]
```

Comment: sort takes TWO arguments that are COMPARED - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: It sorts the array by always placing the second item before the first, irrespective of the actual content. You could just as easily write `a.sort(() => 1)`.

Comment: `sort` cannot be used to reverse an arbitrary array. If you try, it will horribly fail at some point.

Comment: I read the documentation after I posted the question and I found the answer but thanks